# Identification of Difference in Weighted Mean and its Standard Error in Clustered Data Using Stata

Tags: stata, covariance-matrix, weighted-regression, weighted-mean, clustered-standard-errors

I already asked this question on the [statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/600086-identification-of-difference-in-weighted-mean-and-its-standard-error-in-clustered-data) but have not received any comments on this issue yet. So I am going to post it here too.

I am concerned with the following problem. Suppose my data looks like this:

```
group   yvar    xvar
1   0.1     50
1   0.2     20
1   0.05    30
2   0.2     10
2   0.1     40
2   0.15    10
```

I am interested in the difference in the xvar weighted mean of yvar between group 1 and group 2 but I am unsure which weighting procedure I should use to obtain valid estimates for the standard error of the difference. Think of xvar as a measure of size and I simply want to give observations with a greater size a larger weight in my linear model.

When I type:

```
reg yvar i.group [aweight=xvar], cluster(group)
```

it correctly gives me the difference in the weighted mean (which is 0.02). However, the Stata tutorial states:

> Analytic weights—analytic is a term we made up—statistically arise in
> one particular problem: linear regression on data that are themselves
> observed means.

and that is what confuses me: Here xvar is a simple size variable and neither the yvar's nor the xvar's are means themselves. On the other side, fweights and iweights are also not appropriate here since xvar does not say anything about the sampling frequency and does not represent a number of several equivalent observations. So my question is whether aweight is correct in this case?

Also, when I calculate weights by hand and rerun the command standard errors are much smaller:

```
bysort group: egen totsize = total(xvar)
gen weight = xvar/totsize
reg yvar i.group [aweight=weight], cluster(group)
```

which I guess is due to the fact that variation in weights is lower. Is this a better approach when one is concerned in estimating the difference in the weighted mean between these two groups?

**Additional Example**

I can also simulate data to make this issue more accessible.

```
clear
set obs 500
set seed 123
gen man = int((_n-1)/20)+1 
gen weight = 250+(1000-250)*runiform() 
gen skill = .
forvalues i=1/25 {
    local a = rnormal(0, 0.1)
    replace skill = `a' if man == `i'
}
gen rndret = rnormal(0.08, 0.2)
gen ret = skill+rndret
reg ret i.man [aweight=weight], cluster(man)
estimates store a

bysort man: egen sumwei = total(weight)
gen weight2 = weight/sumwei
reg ret i.man [aweight=weight2], cluster(man)
estimates store b
esttab a b
```

Here I simulate 25 groups where the variable of interest (*ret*) is the sum of a group level variable (*skill*) and a random component (*rndret*). Once again I am not sure if aweight is the appropriate choice here and if weighting with *weight2* is to be preferred over weighting with *weight*.

Comment: Why not use [importance weights](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-02/msg00525.html)? Also, clustering with two groups seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks for your comment, Dimitriy. I also thought about using iweight. However, it is not feasible to estimate cluster robust standard errors using this option. All I want is an estimate for the standard error of the weighted mean in presence of cluster correlated errors. Does not look like iweight is helping me on this way, does it? Maybe as an side note: The example given here is a toy example. My real data has a few hundred clusters.

Comment: Can you expand your data?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: Do you mean a "bigger" toy example? I am going to add one to my question.

Comment: No, the command that clones observations. This can get around the iweight not being allowed as long as you have enough computer memory.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Okay, I see. If I understood you correctly, you propose to duplicate each observation according to its weight and run "simple" regressions without any weight adjustment, right? Could you elaborate a bit on this, please? My concern is that this approach would artificially increase the power of my tests even though the number of observations remains actually unchanged. What do you think about aweight? From my knowledge it just runs a linear regression of the same sort after transforming each variable using the weights: $\frac{y_i}{z_i}=\sum\frac{\beta_k}{z_k}+\frac{u_i}{z_i}$

Comment: I am not sold on using aweights. Perhaps if you clarify why you want to weight the larger groups more heavily there will be another solution.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks for figuring out this issue with me. I hope I can clarify things. Suppose each "group" represents a mutual fund manager who manages several funds. Let the yvar be each fund's return and xvar the fund's size (tna). Now, since all funds by one manager share the same manager's skill etc. it is reasonable to assume that returns are correlated within a "group". As larger fund's are "more important" (provide more fee income, have a higher impact on a manager's reputation etc) I want to give them a higher weight when estimating the average return difference btw managers.